# Creating a Ruby method that pads an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I'm working on creating a method that pads an array, and accepts 1. a desired value and 2. an optional string/integer value.  Desired_size reflects the desired number of elements in the array.  If a string/integer is passed in as the second value, this value is used to pad the array with extra elements.  I understand there is a 'fill' method that can shortcut this - but that would be cheating for the homework I'm doing.

The issue: no matter what I do, only the original array is returned.  I started here:

```
class Array
  def pad(desired_size, value = nil)

    desired_size >= self.length ? return self : (desired_size - self.length).times.do { |x| self << value }

  end
end

test_array = [1, 2, 3]
test_array.pad(5)
```

From what I researched the issue seemed to be around trying to alter self's array, so I learned about .inject and gave that a whirl:

```
class Array
  def pad(desired_size, value = nil)

    if desired_size >= self.length
      return self 
    else 
      (desired_size - self.length).times.inject { |array, x| array << value }
    return array
    end
  end
end
test_array = [1, 2, 3]
test_array.pad(5)
```

The interwebs tell me the problem might be with any reference to self so I wiped that out altogether:

```
class Array
  def pad(desired_size, value = nil)
    array = []
    self.each { |x| array << x }
    if desired_size >= array.length
      return array 
    else 
      (desired_size - array.length).times.inject { |array, x| array << value }
    return array
    end
  end
end
test_array = [1, 2, 3]
test_array.pad(5)
```

I'm very new to classes and still trying to learn about them.  Maybe I'm not even testing them the right way with my test_array?  Otherwise, I think the issue is I get the method to recognize the desired_size value that's being passed in. I don't know where to go next.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Your first try of the `pad` method did not actually run properly, there were errors. If you put this as your pad method it will work (I squeezed it together, so make it more readable by adding spaces and removing semicolons). `(desired_size - self.length).times{self << value}if desired_size>self.length;return self`. Since this was just a small bugfix I comment.

Comment: Have you considered using .map or .map! ? The latter should modify in self I think ... ruby class String has a method to replace itself, called replace(). Not sure if class Array also have something like that, I am afraid it might not have. But it definitely sounds as if .map would be useful here!

Comment: Hint: do you want to pad if the `desired_size` is greater than or smaller than the current size?

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers your code works very nicely, but I'm not sure how I would have fixed my original to make it work as nicely as yours.  I tried to covert it into if/else but no dice...  Jörg: I was to pad if the desired_size is more than the original array's length.  I *think* my code has that bit right - but I'm very new and probably missing something obvious.  Thank you both so much for your help so far!

Comment: @CJJohnson One of the things is; there is no need for an `else`. Think about it. 1. You *always* want to return the Array instance, `self`. 2. You *only* want to do something if `desired_size` is larger than `self.length`. That's what I changed; check if `desired_size > self.length` and in that case pad stuff. Otherwise we do not have to do anything, except return `self` like we also do in the other case. Since they share the `return self`, you should not put that inside separate `if/else` blocks.

Comment: As others have mentioned, all you need is to change `>=` to `<=` and drop the `return` (which is a syntax error). No real problem to address.

Comment: @DaniëlKnippers You are the man!  Thank you for explaining my very silly error.  Got this code finally working.  Victory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all 3 of your tries, you are returning the original array if desired_size is greater than the original array size.  You have that backwards.  In other words, you just return instead of padding.

Your first attempt was close.  You need to:
1) Fix your conditional check.
2) It's OK to modify the self array, so the more complicated tries are not necessary.
3) Make sure you return self no matter what you do.

By modifying self, not only do you return the modified array, but you also change the array held by the variable `test_array`.  So if you were to do:

```
test_array = [1, 2, 3]
puts test_array.pad(5, 4).inspect  // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
puts test_array                    // prints [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
```

In Ruby, when a function modifies self, the function name ends with a `!`, so if you were to write it modifying self, it would be better to name it `pad!`.

If you want to write it so that it doesn't modify self, you could start with:

```
array = self.dup
```

and then do all of your operations on `array`.